# c# Mvc Entity Framework issue with WHERE clause and Boolean values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, lambda

can someone please assist me adjust my syntax below. I keep getting an error that says "Error   403 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
var workerRecords =
    from oe in context.tbl_Company_Workers.ToList() 
    where( 
        w => w.WorkerRoleID.HasValue && w.WorkerRoleID == 3
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: you need a Select clause before your ToList()

Comment: @tschmit007 I think `where` and `ToList()` is enough to get this work .Please correct me if I'm wrong , I use select if i'm selecting particular properties only .`var result = Collection.Where(g=>g.Id >5).ToList()` and `var result2 = Collection.Where(g=>g.Id>5).Select(h=>h.Id).ToList();`

Comment: I think this may return Workers with this filter `var workerRecords  = context.tbl_Company_Workers.Where(w => w.WorkerRoleID.HasValue && w.WorkerRoleID == 3).ToList();`

Comment: @tschmit007 sorry , I was wrong, Linq must definitely need a projection `Select` to get the data .

Answer (score 1):

```
var workerRecords =
    (from oe in context.tbl_Company_Workers 
    where w.WorkerRoleID.HasValue && w.WorkerRoleID == 3
    select oe).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need  w.WorkerRoleID.HasValue if you are strictly selecting 3?

```
var workerRecords =
    (from oe in context.tbl_Company_Workers.ToList() 
    where oe.WorkerRoleID == 3 select oe
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please chekc using statements

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class Class1
{
 public void MethodName()
   {
    var workerRecords = context.tbl_Company_Workers.where(cw =>     w.WorkerRoleID.HasValue && w.WorkerRoleID.Value == 3).ToList();
    }
 }
```